# Recover Data of Lost Partition Table of Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, gpt

Actually I was formatting my Dell Vostro Laptop. And while doing that a message showed up that "you cannot install OS in this partition. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style." I have search the solution in technet.microsoft.com and one answer i got is to "To manually wipe a drive and convert it to GPT: " and solution found is

**From inside Windows Setup, press Shift+F10 to open a command prompt window.
Open the diskpart tool:
diskpart
Identify the drive to reformat:
list disk
Select the drive, and reformat it:
select disk 
clean
convert gpt
exit**

And after that when i opened custom installation type. I found that all my hard disk got unallocated.

Kindly provide me solution to get my Partition table back or any solution to recover my data.

Please help me. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @DavidPostill, this is not a duplicate. The user is specifically asking about a deleted partition table.

Comment: @Louis Duplicate explains how to do that (i.e TestDisk )

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I noticed that, but most questions about HDD recovery/reconstruction won't map to an answer there. At least not in the sense that someone will see the question and write the detailed answer that they might have written here.